# Getting string inside an array form simplexml xpath query result

Tags: php, simplexml

i am working with an xml, using simplexml and xpath now when i echo a result of xpth query it echoing string but i need to get that string in a array, but when trying to copy in a array it is coming as and simplexml object, like

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#237 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(69) "Hallituksen esitykset uusiksi Yle-laeiksi eduskunnan kÃ¤siteltÃ¤viksi"
}
```

is just want "Hallituksen esitykset uusiksi Yle-laeiksi eduskunnan kÃ¤siteltÃ¤viksi" here is the code,

```
        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>" . $pageBlocks['news'];
        $xmldata = simplexml_load_string($xml);


        $result = $xmldata->xpath('/blocks/block/items/item/strong');

        $feeddata = array();

        while (list(, $node) = each($result)) {
            $feeddata [] = $node[0];
        }

        foreach ($feeddata as $data){
            var_dump($data);
        }
```

how to solve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it as a string, simply cast it via `(string)`, which will internally call SimpleXMLElement's `__toString()` to return a string representation. That's what's also happening implicitly when you `echo` it, incidentally.

```
while (list(, $node) = each($result)) {
    $feeddata [] = (string)$node[0];
}
```

Comment: I love SimpleXML also for this feature.

Comment: @lorenzo-s I "grew up" on DOMDocument, but have mostly switched to SimpleXML because of this ease of use.